# Solidity msg.value Not Transferring To Desired Address

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

Im writing up a simple solidity function in attempt to transfer some value to a specific address from the knights array.

I call the giveToKnights() function and input the address and the index but no value gets transferred to the desired knights address.

I am not sure if it's because the contract has no ether to actually give to the selected knight? If that <- is why was I hoping someone could help show me how to supply the contract with some ether to give out.

happy to clarify if that ^ was not clear.

```
address[] public knights = [0x14723a09acff6d2a60dcdf7aa4aff308fddc160c, 0x4b0897b0513fdc7c541b6d9d7e929c4e5364d2db, 0x4b0897b0513fdc7c541b6d9d7e929c4e5364d2db, 0xdd870fa1b7c4700f2bd7f44238821c26f7392148];


function giveToKnights(uint _knightIndex, address _knightPlayer) payable public {

      swipees[_swipeeIndex].transfer(msg.value);

}
```

Comment: What is `swipees` and `swipeeIndex`? Is it supposed to be `knights[_knightIndex].transfer()`. If so, what is `_knightPlayer` used for? Provide reproducible code and maybe we can help.

Comment: Also, there are plenty of answers provided on SO and ethereum.stackexchange.com, along with tutorials online, that show how to send ether from a client.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use an IDE with a debugger, such as [remix](https://remix.ethereum.org), it will directly show you issues with your code:

> ```
> browser/StackOverflow:7:11: DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
>       swipees[_swipeeIndex].transfer(msg.value);
>       ^-----^
> browser/StackOverflow:7:19: DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
>       swipees[_swipeeIndex].transfer(msg.value);
>               ^----------^
> ```

You probably mixed up the variable names, the following compiles:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.9;

contract StackOverflow {
    address[] public knights = [0x14723a09acff6d2a60dcdf7aa4aff308fddc160c, 0x4b0897b0513fdc7c541b6d9d7e929c4e5364d2db, 0x4b0897b0513fdc7c541b6d9d7e929c4e5364d2db, 0xdd870fa1b7c4700f2bd7f44238821c26f7392148];

    function giveToKnights(uint _knightIndex, address _knightPlayer) payable public {
          knights[_knightIndex].transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

However, `_knightPlayer` is still unused.

> ```
> browser/StackOverflow:6:47: Warning: Unused function parameter. Remove or comment out the variable name to silence this warning.
> function giveToKnights(uint _knightIndex, address _knightPlayer) payable public {
>                                           ^-------------------^
> ```

I hope that helps. I would recommend to directly send the Ether to `_knightPlayer` in this scenario, this makes the array obsolete.